# NHibernate ISession usage and thread safety

Tags: nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-2, autofac

When I configure my ISession lifetime to be 'per HTTP request' (InstancePerLifetimeScope in Autofac which I'm using), NHibernate profiler tells me that my Session is being used across threads, which is most likely a bug. What is going on?
I'm used to thinking that I should scope unit of work to http request but it seems that session is indeed being used across threds.

Essentially this 'ISession per HTTP request' conflicts with NHibernate profiler alerts.
Where am I wrong?

UPDATE: I do have a ContainerDisposalModule in my Web.config, so the disposing works as it should

Comment: Silent downvoters please comment your decision, thanks!

Comment: +1 to counter downvote. This is a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: Do you have ContainerDisposalModule in the correct section of Web.config for your version of IIS? The other thread may be the finalizer..

Answer (score 1):

IIS (like most web servers) uses multiple threads to serve requests so this is probably not a bug in your application and you can safely ignore the warnings.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435492/is-asp-net-multithreaded-how-does-it-execute-requests).

Comment: I know that asp.net executes every request on a thread taken from the thread pool. But AFAIK it should not use multiple threads within single request. Every request is single-threaded inside, isn't it?

Comment: @Valentin Vasiliev: It can hop threads if its async - dont assume all work is processed on same thread

Comment: "If its async" - what is async? I'm not using async controllers. And I assume that when controller is instantiated its action method is invoked on one and only thread. So the question still holds, how is it possible that NH prof detects usage across threads within *one* instance of asp.net mvc controller?

Comment: IIS/ASP.NET can and does use multiple threads to handle a single request. For example, it may load external files (.js or images) on another thread. You can easily demonstrate this by disposing the ISession in Session_EndRequest -- this will occasionally result in a "no session or session was closed" error.